# Logstash error: Pipeline error {:pipeline_id=>"main", :exception=>#<Grok::PatternError: pattern %{JOBNAME:project} not defined>,

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, kibana, elk

> `your text`Logstash keeps crashing and I'm not sure what the issue is

Full log:
[2022-03-30T18:21:34,633][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600, :ssl_enabled=>false}
[2022-03-30T18:21:37,520][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 167 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 119 keys and 417 values
[2022-03-30T18:21:39,677][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["http://104.154.51.160:9200"]}
[2022-03-30T18:21:40,456][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://104.154.51.160:9200/]}}
[2022-03-30T18:21:40,912][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://104.154.51.160:9200/"}
[2022-03-30T18:21:40,944][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch version determined (7.17.1) {:es_version=>7}
[2022-03-30T18:21:40,957][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
[2022-03-30T18:21:41,089][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Config is not compliant with data streams. `data_stream => auto` resolved to `false`
[2022-03-30T18:21:41,094][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Config is not compliant with data streams. `data_stream => auto` resolved to `false`
[2022-03-30T18:21:41,209][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Using a default mapping template {:es_version=>7, :ecs_compatibility=>:disabled}
[2022-03-30T18:21:41,559][ERROR][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline error {:pipeline_id=>"main", :exception=>#<Grok::PatternError: pattern %{JOBNAME:project} not defined>, :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/jls-grok-0.11.5/lib/grok-pure.rb:123:in `block in compile'", "org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1442:in` loop'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/jls-grok-0.11.5/lib/grok-pure.rb:93:in `compile'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-filter-grok-4.4.1/lib/logstash/filters/grok.rb:282:in` block in register'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1821:in `each'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-filter-grok-4.4.1/lib/logstash/filters/grok.rb:276:in` block in register'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1415:in `each'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-filter-grok-4.4.1/lib/logstash/filters/grok.rb:271:in` register'", "org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/AbstractFilterDelegatorExt.java:75:in `register'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:232:in` block in register_plugins'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1821:in `each'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:231:in` register_plugins'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:590:in `maybe_setup_out_plugins'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:244:in` start_workers'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:189:in `run'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:141:in` block in start'"], "pipeline.sources"=>["/etc/logstash/conf.d/jenkins.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x7b168333 run>"}
[2022-03-30T18:21:41,570][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline terminated {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[2022-03-30T18:21:41,597][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:id=>:main, :action_type=>LogStash::ConvergeResult::FailedAction, :message=>"Could not execute action: PipelineAction::Create<main>, action_result: false", :backtrace=>nil}
[2022-03-30T18:21:41,780][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.
[2022-03-30T18:21:41,801][FATAL][org.logstash.Logstash    ] Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
org.jruby.exceptions.SystemExit: (SystemExit) exit
at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:747) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.20.1.jar:?]
at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:710) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.20.1.jar:?]
at usr.share.logstash.lib.bootstrap.environment.<main>(/usr/share/logstash/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:94) ~[?:?]

My conf file

`input { 
beats { 
port => 5000 
type => jenkins 
} 
}

filter { 
if [type] == "jenkins" { 
grok { 
patterns_dir => ["/etc/logstash/patterns"] 
match => { 
"message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:createdAt}%{SPACE}[id=%{INT:buildId}]%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{SPACE}%{JAVACLASS:class}%{DATA:state}:%{SPACE}%{JOBNAME:project} #%{NUMBER:buildNumber} %{DATA:execution}: %{WORD:status}" 
} 
} 
} 
}

output { 
if [type] == "jenkins" { 
elasticsearch { 
hosts => 'elasticsearch server ip goes in here' 
index => 'jenkins-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}' 
} 
} 
} 
`
I was thinking it wasn't seeing my conf file but then this line was in the logs referring to it:
"pipeline.sources"=>["/etc/logstash/conf.d/jenkins.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x7b168333 run>"}

I'm confused please help!

Comment: This is your error _<Grok::PatternError: pattern %{JOBNAME:project} not defined>_, logstash can't find the grok pattern `JOBNAME`, which is a custom pattern. What do you have in `/etc/logstash/patterns`? Update your question and share your custom patterns.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @leandrojmp Thank you for replying! I don't have that directory, I'm trying to see what caused that

Comment: It is in your config `patterns_dir => ["/etc/logstash/patterns"]` and your grok filter is using the `JOBNAME` pattern. Did you copy the config file from other place?

Comment: @leandrojmp I really appreciate the help! I've created the directory and custom pattern thank you